# How to get a variable from WSDL with mule setvariable and datamapper? Message payload is of type: HashMap

Tags: soap, wsdl, mule

It should be simple but I can't set it working. My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.6.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" wsdlLocation="http://procese/sysworkflow/en/classic/services/wsdl2" service="ProcessMakerService" port="ProcessMakerServiceSoap" serviceAddress="http://procese:80/sysworkflow/en/classic/services/soap2" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <data-mapper:config name="JSON_To_XML" transformationGraphPath="json_to_xml.grf" doc:name="JSON_To_XML"/>
    <flow name="ws_pm_login3Flow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="#[{&quot;userid&quot;:&quot;xyz.qwe&quot;, &quot;password&quot;:&quot;12345&quot;}]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="JSON_To_XML" doc:name="JSON To XML"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="login" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

The WS is working fine.

The mapper file json_to_xml.grf looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Graph __version="3.5.0" author="abc" created="Tue Apr 21 13:27:56 EEST 2015" description="JSON To XML" guiVersion="3.4.4.P" id="1429614596881" licenseCode="Unlicensed" licenseType="Unknown" modified="Tue Apr 21 13:27:56 EEST 2015" modifiedBy="abc" name="JSON_To_XML" revision="1.0" showComponentDetails="false">
<Global>
<Metadata __index="0" __referenceCounter="1" __sourcePath="{}/login" _dataStructure="OBJECT" _id="__id" _type="Input" id="e941872a-c0e5-4148-ac8c-6010c4dad903">
<Record fieldDelimiter="," name="login" recordDelimiter="\n\\|\r\n\\|\r" type="delimited">
<Field __artificialType="_id" __systemManaged="true" name="__id" type="string"/>
<Field __index="1" __sourcePath="{}/login/password" containerType="SINGLE" label="password" name="password" type="string"/>
<Field __index="0" __sourcePath="{}/login/userid" containerType="SINGLE" label="userid" name="userid" type="string"/>
</Record>
</Metadata>
<Metadata __index="0" __referenceCounter="1" __sourcePath="{}/login" _dataStructure="OBJECT" _id="__id" _type="Output" id="d9e5b0f6-b757-46cb-89bf-a7662be5c77f">
<Record fieldDelimiter="," name="login" recordDelimiter="\n\\|\r\n\\|\r" type="delimited">
<Field __artificialType="_id" __systemManaged="true" name="__id" type="string"/>
<Field __index="0" __sourcePath="{}/login/password" containerType="SINGLE" label="password" name="password" type="string"/>
<Field __index="1" __sourcePath="{}/login/userid" containerType="SINGLE" label="userid" name="userid" type="string"/>
</Record>
</Metadata>
<Dictionary>
<Entry id="DictionaryEntry0" input="true" name="inputPayload" output="false" type="object"/>
<Entry id="DictionaryEntry1" input="false" name="outputPayload" output="true" type="object"/>
</Dictionary>
</Global>
<Phase number="0">
<Node cacheInMemory="true" charset="UTF-8" enabled="enabled" fileURL="dict:outputPayload" guiName="XML WRITER" guiX="900" guiY="20" id="EXT_XML_WRITER0" type="EXT_XML_WRITER">
<attr name="mapping"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<login xmlns:clover="http://www.cloveretl.com/ns/xmlmapping" clover:inPort="0">
  <password>$0.password</password>
  <userid>$0.userid</userid>
</login>]]></attr>
<attr name="_data_format"><![CDATA[XML]]></attr>
</Node>
<Node enabled="enabled" guiName="Foreach 'login' -&gt; 'login'" guiX="460" guiY="20" id="FOREACH_LOGIN_LOGIN" transformClass="com.mulesoft.datamapper.transform.MelRecordTransform" type="REFORMAT">
<attr name="melScript"><![CDATA[//MEL
//START -> DO NOT REMOVE
output.__id = input.__id;
//END -> DO NOT REMOVE
output.password = input.password;
output.userid = input.userid;
]]></attr>
</Node>
<Node charset="UTF-8" enabled="enabled" fileURL="dict:inputPayload" guiName="JSON READER" guiX="20" guiY="20" id="JSON_READER0" type="JSON_READER">
<attr name="mapping"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Context xpath="/root">
  <Context outPort="0" sequenceField="__id" xpath="object">
    <Mapping cloverField="password" trim="true" xpath="password"/>
    <Mapping cloverField="userid" trim="true" xpath="userid"/>
  </Context>
</Context>
]]></attr>
<attr name="_data_format"><![CDATA[JSON]]></attr>
</Node>
<Edge debugMode="true" fromNode="FOREACH_LOGIN_LOGIN:0" guiBendpoints="" id="Edge1" inPort="Port 0 (in)" metadata="d9e5b0f6-b757-46cb-89bf-a7662be5c77f" outPort="Port 0 (out)" toNode="EXT_XML_WRITER0:0"/>
<Edge debugMode="true" fromNode="JSON_READER0:0" guiBendpoints="" id="Edge0" inPort="Port 0 (in)" metadata="e941872a-c0e5-4148-ac8c-6010c4dad903" outPort="Port 0 (out)" toNode="FOREACH_LOGIN_LOGIN:0"/>
</Phase>
</Graph>
```

When I start the process I get:

```
Error executing graph: ERROR (com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.exception.DataMapperExecutionException). Message payload is of type: HashMap
```

I am using 3.6.1 EE

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is a problem in mule to use the double quotes in JSON. I swithced to XML and now it is working fine.